# Turn on the Blue light filter with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to turn on/off the Android Blue Light Filter.

I already have tried to use an Action via `Intent`, the `ACTION_NIGHT_DISPLAY_SETTINGS`, but it returns me an error: **No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.settings.NIGHT_DISPLAY_SETTINGS }**

I am very new to Kotlin and Native Android development (started studying 3 days ago).

I also saw that there's an feature called `ContentResolver` that can change values in another application, I'm guessing if there's a way to change it by ContentResolver.

Thank you for any information.

Comment: check this repo https://github.com/code-crusher/Dimmer